# How to Store PDF Content In String Base64 format

Tags: java, pdf, itext, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I want to store a PDF in Base64 format before sending it to a `FileOutputStream`. I tried the code below. I tried using the `write` method of `OutputStream` with anonymous inner class but the content gets null.

```
package com.hmkcode;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;

public class App 
{
    public static final String HTML = "<h1>Hello</h1>"
        + "<p>This was created using iText</p>"
        + "<a href='hmkcode.com'>hmkcode.com</a>";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HTML, new FileOutputStream("string-to-pdf.pdf"));
        System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `wrap` method of the `java.util.Base64.Encoder` class to get an `OutputStream` that performs Base64 encoding to anything written to it:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pdf-base64.txt");
OutputStream base64os = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(fos);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HTML, base64os);
```

Note that the documentation says to close the Base64 output stream:

> It is recommended to promptly close the returned output stream after use, during which it will flush all possible leftover bytes to the underlying output stream. Closing the returned output stream will close the underlying output stream.

`convertToPdf` closes the output stream automatically, but if you're creating the PDF in a different way, make sure to call `base64os.close()`.

---

If for some reason you want to create the PDF first and do the Base64 encoding afterwards, you can use one of the many Base64 encoding implementations out there. For example, using `java.util.Base64.Encoder`:

```
// Create PDF
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HTML, baos);

// Generate Base64 encoded version of PDF
byte[] base64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray());

// Write Base64 data to file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pdf-base64.txt");
fos.write(base64encoded);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Thank You for the quick response sir. I had tried the same but if I am decoding the encoded data then I an getting empty page.actually I am creating a rest client and I have to send this html to callee in pdf(base64 encoded) format if I am storing the data in file then the file is proper but if I ma sending as response then there is only white page

Comment: If the data decodes correctly when stored in a local file, but not after sending, then the issue is likely in the sending (or receiving). Store the received data in a file and compare it with the local file. Since you only have a white page, my guess is the data is truncated, i.e. you're not sending all the data. The data will still resemble a PDF file well enough for the PDF viewer to open it, but it cannot display all the page content properly.

Comment: Thank you rhens for your guidance I got the proper result as per the requirement as I followed your given code.. thanks

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers